# In Zoom chat, how do you return to lock on Everyone?

Tags: chat, zoom-meeting

When you send a message Directly to a specific person, Zoom locks the person in so that after sending a message, the default target is that person, not Everyone. How do you unlock this mode so that Everyone becomes the default again?

Answer (score 0):

Just choose "everyone" from the dropdown and send a message. Everyone will stick from that moment on.

EDIT: However, if you get a private message from a person, Zoom will default to that person and you have to change manually to "everyone".

If you are the host, you can control who can chat with whom by clicking "More ..." in the chat window, and selecting the desired option of "Participants can chat with"

See also the relevant [Zoom help article](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360060835932-Enabling-and-disabling-private-chat#h_d9a04597-0138-4fb9-86cd-81cc4c68b21f)

Comment: The point is that it is my experience that sending a message to Everyone doesn't always unlock sending to a specific person. The default recipient doesn't always change to Everyone. This might happen if the specific person sends a message back, I'm not sure. Does anyone else have this problem?

Comment: @DavidSpector see my edit

Comment: I can't find any edit at 1NN.